# Subtraction Magmas

Tags: abstract-algebra, magma

I was looking at a collection of related closed binary operations on sets ([magmas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magma_(algebra))):

- Subtraction on the integers, reals, etc.
- Set difference
- Set symmetric difference
- Saturating subtraction on the nonnegative integers
- Ceilinged division on the positive integers

Each of these operations has the following properties, where the operation is represented by $\sim$:

1. There exists an identity element $e$ such that for all elements $a$:
   $$a \sim a = e \text{ and } a \sim e = a$$
2. For all elements $a, b, c$:
   $$(a \sim b) \sim c = (a \sim c) \sim b$$

I call these operations **subtraction magmas** because they often take the form of some kind of subtraction.

I have two questions:

1. Do these operations share any other nontrivial properties? That is, is there a tighter characterization of these operations?
2. Have such operations been studied in the past?

Comment: Your examples are close to [quasigroups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasigroup) and [loops](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/AlgebraicLoop.html), but not quite (set symmetric difference is a loop, i think, and so are integers and reals with subtraction, while set difference and saturated subtraction on the naturals are not).

Comment: @Arthur Integers and real numbers with subtraction are not loops because they have no identity. $0$ is a right identity for $-$ over $\mathbb{Z}$ or $\mathbb{R}$ but not a left identity: $a=a-0\ne 0-a=-a$ for all $a\in\mathbb{R}$ :)